# Share exact Gb via webdav

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav, share

How can i share exactly e.g. 5 Gb via WebDAV for a user without partitioning?

I would like to do it for 20 users so every user would get different 5Gb personal space.

The operational system is Centos6 with apache2 and php5 with mysql.

The user authenticationg would happen by mysql_auth or with a password file.

Mysql would be easier i think.

But the main point is they could only upload 5Gb amiunt of files.

Sorry for the bad English.

Thanks
Ewert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RFC4331: Quota and Size Properties for Distributed Authoring and Versioning (DAV) Collections seems to be part of your solution. You can look the RFC for it on the tools.ietf.org website.

A Linux Gazette article called [WebDAV: Life in the fast lane](http://linuxgazette.net/131/cressatti.html) has an old method of adding the quota feature to mod_webdav worth reviewing for concepts. A more recent version of the code appears to be "[mod_dav_fs_diskquota](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/webdav/)" found on Japanese SourceForge. This support does not appear to be included in the base Apache webdav module according to several sources.

You specifically said you do not want to separate the repositories but that is likely to be the easiest solution. Then you can just use the base OS file system quotas to enforce the limits. The first article above included several authentication methods that would assist in this configuration and worth a read.

I hope this helps and I'm interested in hearing how your endeavor turns out.